# Searching for title of story where children are wild and live outside the city

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I read a short story many years ago that I would like to find for my kids.  Have googled like mad to no avail. Here is what I remember:

- Set in a dystopian future,
- A couple puts on some special skin suits so they can have relations.

  - Then they discuss their desire to adopt a child and how they found a broker who can help them.
- You learn that what children there are are wild and live outside the city.
- They drive out of the city into some ruined/abandoned area where the broker, an old man, is waiting at an old parking garage.
- In the end, it is the wild kids who control the broker, not the other way around and they have used this ruse to lure the couple into their trap.

Comment: When was many years ago? And also, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: What kind of "trap"?

Comment: Sometime between 1986 and 1991. To eat them?